# Нахождение повторяющихся элементов в строке с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка, например:

```
JJJJJJJJOIIIIIGFGNJGFJJJPPPPKDGKJUUUU
```

Надо получить все подстроки с повторяющимися символами, т.е.:

```
JJJJJJJJ, IIIII, JJJ, PPPP, UUUU.
```

Никак не могу подобрать, какой тут применить шаблон?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CvsXJm/1

Comment: @splash58 это да, но Ваш шаблон ищет только символы, а не подстроки... Символы и с помощью Counter'а из collections можно посчитать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
s = 'JJJJJJJJOIIIIIGFGNJGFJJJPPPPKDGKJUUUU'

res = [match.group() for match in re.finditer(r'(.)\1+', s)]
```

результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]: ['JJJJJJJJ', 'IIIII', 'JJJ', 'PPPP', 'UUUU']
```